# Need help identifying this three-layer diverging diamond-style interchange

Tags: civil-engineering, bridges, traffic-intersections

I'm an avid fan of Cities: Skylines, and it has occurred to me that one of the types of interchanges that seems to fare very well with the simulated traffic is this three-layer diverging diamond (style) interchange. I realize this isn't a true DDI, because they require traffic lights in a staggered traffic flow on the same second level.

Is there a name for this specific type of interchange, and do they work as well in real life as they do in simulated life?

[image]

Source: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=636634176

Comment: Too much is elevated, especially with East extending over West itms.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. This height and positioning of nodes isn’t very realistic. But in real life it could be done, there’s still a good chance it could work well, with the same left-lane-turns-left of a DDI.

Comment: You'd have to balance overall cost vs benefits.  You have exits on right and left.  Even with good signage newbs would miss turn.  It works in the game because you can link lanes with exits and the little electrons follow those rules religiously.  Real world has too many idiots to outweigh any benefits.

Comment: Same argument for DDI, though? I think it would have to be done with good signage and concrete barriers well in advance to the intersection. Also materials cost vs. A full cloverleaf would be less, I would think.

Comment: Not for elevated highway.

Comment: There is also some philosophy out there that you tend to merge into the main line of traffic from the same side of the road.  In north america most traffic will merge in from your right.  There are exception.  You will note that in this configuration there are lanes merging from both the left and right side from some of those pass over lanes.  This can lead to lane changes, which in turn can slow down traffic.